# Adding a variable to the verbatim string literal

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, restsharp, verbatim-string

I am new to C# programming.

I am trying to automate some API tests and passing payload in a POST request using RestSharp library. That payload looks like this

```
public class Payload
    {
        public string firstPayload = @"{
" + "\n" +
@"  ""channel"": ""XYZ"",
" + "\n" +
@"  ""Email"": ""abc@abc.com""
" + "\n" +
@"}";
}
```

I call this payload in the Test Project. This request will look something like this in Postman (JSON)

```
{
  "channel": "XYZ",
  "Email": "abc@abc.com"
}
```

But since I can't use the same email over and over, now I want to add (DateTime.Now) in YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS format with the email, so that everytime I run my test, it's a unique email. The email should look like *"abc20220825124587@abc.com"*

**But I am not sure how to add current date time within the verbatim string firstPayload C# code**

Comment: You don't need to have `+ "\n" +`, your verbatim string will pick up the new lines that you have typed into your strings.  In addition to that, you should consider `Environment.NewLine` as the newline character.  To insert stuff into your strings, look at _Interpolated Strings_ (which can be mixed with verbatim strings): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation#how-to-use-escape-sequences-in-an-interpolated-string

Comment: I suggest using a json serializer library. The most used ones are [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0)

Comment: If you are using RestSharp it includes built in serialization that can do a lot of this lifting for you. You might want to check out https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addjsonbody on their official documentation.

Additionally you can manually serialize the object using something like System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft and add it to the POST body as stated above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var payload = $@"
{{
    ""channel"": ""XYZ"",
    ""Email"": ""abc{DateTime.Now}@abc.com""
}}";
```

You don't need to manually add `"/n"` when using string literal

Comment: It worked. I just used {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")} in order to achieve the format compatible with email